# SQL group by left empty if different value

Tags: mysql

sql question

i have table like:

```
id | Animal | country | gender | qty
1  | cow    | USA     | male   | 6
2  | cow    | PHP     | female | 8
3  | cow    | USA     | male   | 7
4  | cow    | JPN     | male   | 6
5  | cow    | USA     | female | 5
```

how to make some result like

```
   | Animal | country | gender | qty
   | cow    | USA     |        | 18 (sumqty for cow from USA)
   | cow    | PHP     | female | 8
   | cow    | JPN     | male   | 6
```

in word something like if animal are same and same country, sum(qty) and leave empty gender because it mix male and female.

i use code like this

```
SELECT *,sum(qty) as sqty FROM myTable GROUP BY animal,country
```

but result when echo ['gender'] it shown a last value(#5)
how make it work?
not, i have much animal. like chicken, duck and ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement to do what you want.  It is a little unclear when you want `age` to be blank, but:

```
select animal, country,
       (case when min(age) = max(age) then min(age) end) as age,
       sum(qty)
from myTable
group by animal, country;
```

Comment: how if not age ( not INT) i mean how if is some word(text or varhcar). wait for my green check i want try your code.

Comment: @Student . . . The type makes no difference for this logic.

Comment: hi i change my example can you help me once more?